# Not able to push the changes to my fork in stash

Tags: git

There is an original repo and I made a fork of that repo. Initially I was not able to clone my fork in IDE however once I made the repo public, I was able to clone it successfully.

Now I have made my code changes and want to push the changes back to git to my fork, however when trying to do the same, I have the below error

> Remote error: Insufficient permissions You cannot push to
> ~myfork/reponame. Pushing requires write access and your access is
> read-only.

I have admin access to my repo and not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Does your IDE know about the security key for the repo? It's not just a matter of you personally having access, but your local machine having access.

Comment: I am pretty new to development and hence can you please let me know how to set up the security key on the IDE. I am using Intelli J on a mac.

Comment: There's plenty of documentation to be found on that. It's not appropriate to ask here in a comment. Please take the [tour].